# spin button for add to cart button - magento 1.7

Tags: php, ajax, xml, magento-1.7, block

I'm new to programming in magento. I want personalized products list magento. Indeed, I would add any button next to the button "Add".
You will find below a screen capture which I will explain.
could you told me what to do please?

(product list page : \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml)

in my list.phtml file, i edit the instruction under isSaleable()): ?> around line 90 to:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">                               
                <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>                                 
                <span class="addToBox">
                <?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?> <input name="qty" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qty" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product)== null?1:$this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>"/> 
                <?php endif; ?> 
                <button class="form-button" type="submit"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></button>
                </span>
            </form>             
        <?php else: ?>
```

and it work but i need to make an spinbutton.

thanks in advance for your help and suggestion.
here's in a picture an illustration.

[image: desired]

Comment: What have you tried? Generally, making an effort before asking a question here will get you off to a better start. Show the code you've attempted.

Comment: Hi, please see behind a code that i make. i'm waiting for your help

Comment: This might be useful for u.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992921/magento-use-quantity-increments-and-ajax-add-to-cart-on-category-page-and-prod and http://jigowatt.co.uk/blog/magento-quantity-increments-jquery-edition/