# How to add plus + and minus - button in quantity box of product listing page (list.phtml)

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento-1.9

Below is my code,

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setQty(id, url) {
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty_' + id).value;
    document.getElementById('cart_button_' + id).innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setLocation(\'' + url + 'qty/' + qty + '/\')"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>';   
}
</script>
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
<input type="text" name="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" maxlength="12" value="1" onkeyup="setQty(<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
<span id="cart_button_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><button type="button" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></span>  
<?php else: ?>
```

the above code i replaced by previous code(below code)

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php else: ?>
```

now it is adding the quantity into the cart but i have to put manually into the box, i want to add + and - button for increasing and decreasing the quantity, what should i do.
I tried lots of things but it is not working here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992921/magento-use-quantity-increments-and-ajax-add-to-cart-on-category-page-and-prod Here is the answer

Answer (score 1):

If there is no any spacial design require then you can try input type "number" instead of "text", with that field increase and decrease button comes in input box.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

```
<input type="number" name="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" maxlength="12" value="1" onkeyup="setQty(<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
```